# popViewControllerAnimated: From Landscape To Portrait

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm having trouble popping a `UINavigationController` (subclass) from a landscape view to a portrait view.

I have a chain set up from the `window`'s `rootViewController` using `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` down to the individual View Controllers that I present.

So, I have a View Controller that ONLY supports portrait. The next one that is pushed supports landscape as well.

When I push the one that supports landscape and then rotate the device, everything rotates. So far, so good.

Now, when I pop back to the first one, both views rotate BEFORE the animation. So, the second viewController's landscape view (which is really small because of the rotation transform) is pushed away to the right side of the portrait screen.

**I want the landscape view to be pushed away to its right** (the top or bottom of the portrait view controller), **while the portrait view controller is shown in the background.**

How can I accomplish this?

I thought I might try to use an animation controller, but the `UINavigationController`'s delegate method, `navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:` isn't called when popping to a View Controller in a different orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of experimentation I figured out what my problem was. Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

I was trying to over-engineer the chain.

I had a custom container with a child tab bar controller which contained multiple navigation controllers that contained view controllers with different orientation requirements.

My main downfall was assuming that even if a modal window was presented, the system would still ask the window's root view controller first. To account for this situation I added a check in the container that looked like this:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if (self.presentedViewController) { // This check is wrong! Don't do this!
        return [self.presentedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }

    // Pass request to child view controller
}
```

However, this was fundamentally causing my problem in two ways.

First, without this check, UIKit will automatically detect the modal view controller and directly ask for its `supportedInterfaceOrientations`.

Second, the way UIKit handles the animations involves presenting several internal view controllers that we normally would have no idea are there. By checking for a modal view controller in `presentingViewController`, the check was catching them and asking them all for their `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. UIKit isn't meant to behave this way, so I was the one interfering with its operations.

The fix was to implement `supportedInterfaceOrientations` so that it ONLY concerns the view controller's direct descendants (i.e. the view controllers whose `view`s are descendants in the current view controller's view hierarchy). The direct descendants can further pass the request down from there.

Treat modal windows as a completely separate chain, regardless of the presenter.

In other words, **trust `UIKit`**.